# python numpy sum function with axis behavior

Tags: python, numpy

I'm new to Python and numpy so I am just running sample codes and try to tweak them for understanding. I encountered some code about `numpy.sum`, with `axis` parameter but I could not get it running. After sometime (reading scipy docs, trying experiments), I got it running by using `axis = (1,2,3)` instead of `axis = 1`.

The thing is, everywhere I search, they only write `axis = 1` to get it work.

I'm using Python 3.5.3, with numpy 1.12.1
Was there a numpy/python version which has that much difference in behaviour? Or did I just configure it wrong in some way?

```
import numpy as np
from past.builtins import xrange


# sample data
X = np.arange(1, 4*4*3*5+1).reshape(5, 4, 4, 3)
Y = np.arange(5, 4*4*3*8+5).reshape(8, 4, 4, 3)
Xlen = X.shape[0]
Ylen = Y.shape[0]

# allocate some space for whatever calculation
rs = np.zeros((Xlen, Ylen))
rs1 = np.zeros((Xlen, Ylen))

# calculate the result with 2 loops
for i in xrange(Xlen):
    for j in xrange(Ylen):
        rs[i, j] = np.sum(X[i] + Y[j])

# calculate the result with one loop only
for i in xrange(Xlen):
    rs1[i, :] = np.sum(Y + X[i], axis=(1,2,3))

print(rs1 == rs) # same result

# also with one loop, as everywhere on the internet:
for i in xrange(Xlen):
    rs1[i, :] = np.sum(Y + X[i], axis=1)
    # ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (8,4,3) into shape (8)
```

Comment: `axis = 1` sums only that one dimension you specified. The result is an array of dimension `ndim - 1`; in your case it has three dimensions and shape `(8, 4, 3)`. That is not compatible with the output array `rs1[i, :]`, which has only two dimensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
axis : None or int or tuple of ints, optional
    ...
    If axis is a tuple of ints, a sum is performed on all of the axes
    specified in the tuple instead of a single axis or all the axes as
    before.
```

The ability to use a tuple was an addition (v1.7, 2013).  I haven't used it much, and when I've needed it in the MATLAB I used repeated sums, e.g.

```
In [149]: arr = np.arange(24).reshape(2,3,4)
In [150]: arr.sum(axis=(1,2))
Out[150]: array([ 66, 210])
In [151]: arr.sum(axis=2).sum(axis=1)
Out[151]: array([ 66, 210])
```

When doing sequential sums you need to keep in mind that the number of axes changes (unless you use `keepdims`, itself a newish parameter).

---

Your `X,Y` sum:

```
In [160]: rs = np.zeros((Xlen, Ylen),int)
     ...: rs1 = np.zeros((Xlen, Ylen),int)
     ...: 
     ...: # calculate the result with 2 loops
     ...: for i in range(Xlen):
     ...:   for j in range(Ylen):
     ...:     rs[i,j] = np.sum(X[i] + Y[j])
     ...: 
In [161]: rs
Out[161]: 
array([[ 2544,  4848,  7152,  9456, 11760, 14064, 16368, 18672],
       [ 4848,  7152,  9456, 11760, 14064, 16368, 18672, 20976],
       [ 7152,  9456, 11760, 14064, 16368, 18672, 20976, 23280],
       [ 9456, 11760, 14064, 16368, 18672, 20976, 23280, 25584],
       [11760, 14064, 16368, 18672, 20976, 23280, 25584, 27888]])
```

Can be replicated without a loop.

```
In [162]: X.sum((1,2,3))
Out[162]: array([ 1176,  3480,  5784,  8088, 10392])
In [163]: Y.sum((1,2,3))
Out[163]: array([ 1368,  3672,  5976,  8280, 10584, 12888, 15192, 17496])
In [164]: X.sum((1,2,3))[:,None] + Y.sum((1,2,3))
Out[164]: 
array([[ 2544,  4848,  7152,  9456, 11760, 14064, 16368, 18672],
       [ 4848,  7152,  9456, 11760, 14064, 16368, 18672, 20976],
       [ 7152,  9456, 11760, 14064, 16368, 18672, 20976, 23280],
       [ 9456, 11760, 14064, 16368, 18672, 20976, 23280, 25584],
       [11760, 14064, 16368, 18672, 20976, 23280, 25584, 27888]])
```

`np.sum(X[i] + Y[j])` => `np.sum(X[i]) + np.sum(Y[j])`.  `sum(X[i])` sums all elements of `X[i]` (axis=None).  That's the same summing on all axes except the 1st, `X.sum(axis=(1,2,3))[i]`.

```
In [165]: X[0].sum()
Out[165]: 1176
In [166]: X.sum((1,2,3))[0]
Out[166]: 1176
In [167]: X.sum(1).sum(1).sum(1)[0]
Out[167]: 1176
```

As for the broadcasting error, look at the pieces:

```
In [168]: rs1[i,:]
Out[168]: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])   # shape (8,)
In [169]: (Y+X[i]).shape    # (8,4,4,3) + (4,4,3)
Out[169]: (8, 4, 4, 3)
In [170]: (Y+X[i]).sum(1).shape    # sums axis 1, ie one of the 4's
Out[170]: (8, 4, 3)
```

Comment: I first ended up using repeated sums too, but then I found using tuples is easier to read in my case.
Still, I don't understand why lots of people got it work just buy using axis = 1, which would result in a different shape.

Comment: I expect that main justification for the `tuple` option was readability.

Answer (score 0):

To get the same result with only `axis=1` written, we can do a trick of reshaping the dataset beforehand.

```
X = np.reshape(X, (X.shape[0], -1))
Y = np.reshape(Y, (Y.shape[0], -1))

for i in xrange(Xlen):
    rs[i, :] = np.sum(Y + X[i], axis=1)
print(rs)
```

The result:

```
[[  2544.   4848.   7152.   9456.  11760.  14064.  16368.  18672.]
 [  4848.   7152.   9456.  11760.  14064.  16368.  18672.  20976.]
 [  7152.   9456.  11760.  14064.  16368.  18672.  20976.  23280.]
 [  9456.  11760.  14064.  16368.  18672.  20976.  23280.  25584.]
 [ 11760.  14064.  16368.  18672.  20976.  23280.  25584.  27888.]]
```